# How do I filter results by a join in BookshelfJS?

Tags: javascript, mysql, orm, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I have a table that has two relations on it:

Jobs -> Company and
Jobs -> User

I want to select only those jobs that already have a user attached to them and get the user associated with them. I tried:

```
new Job().fetchAll({withRelated: ['user']})
```

However this always returns all the jobs with the user attached. I also tried:

```
new Job().fetchAll({
    withRelated: [{
        'user':function(qb){
            qb.where('id','=','job.user_id');
        }
    }]
});
```

And every combination of user sub queries I could think of. But that only allowed me to filter the results of what was returned by the user relation.

I know SQL but I wanted to use an ORM. So the end query should be like:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs JOIN users ON users.id = jobs.user_id LEFT JOIN companies on job.company_id = companies.id
```

How can I do this using BookshelfJS or Knex?

Comment: Whoever downvoted... can you explain why? A down vote without an explanation is useless.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished it by using the query builder.

```
new Job().query(function(qb){
    qb.innerJoin('users', 'user_id', 'users.id');
}).fetchAll({
   withRelated: ['company', 'users']
});
```

Basically combining Bookshelf with Knex statements.

If this is possible in pure Bookshelf, let me know and I'll upvote the answer!

Comment: Note: new Job({id:1}).query won't filter for 'id=1'. Calling "query" seems to overwrite that constraint.